# Protractor is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, selenium, jenkins, npm, protractor

I have protractor installed on windows slave machine. I am trying to run my script using `node index.js`.
If I trigger job from jenkins to run above command it gives error like `Protractor is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. But when I run command directly on slave machine it execute it successfully.

Comment: Can you check the `PATH` for the Jenkins slave?  It should be available in the Jenkins configuration.  The problem might be that `protractor` is not in the `PATH` for Jenkins.

Comment: Hi @dylants I have added protractor PATH in jenkins slave. I have added it in environment variable as it is windows slave. where else I need to add protractor PATH?

Comment: Try making sure you can execute `protractor` from the command line, logged in as whatever user is running Jenkins on that machine.  If you can not, you'll need to either add it to the `PATH` for your Windows box, or fully qualify the path to the `protractor` executable file.

Comment: I have the same error, where do i need to add PATH? I am new to Jenkins and I have no idea where to add. can you please help on this @dylants

Comment: @Nick If protractor, python, node can not recognized as external or internal command error occurs, check the ENV variables of system and also in jenkins configuration for that node(go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage node -> System Information) If path is not present add it in the environment variable of that node.  Check c:\windows\system32 path in env variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jenkins NodeJS plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) to install node and additional npm packages like protractor, grunt, etc.

After installing npm packages at global level, you can select the "Provide Node & npm bin/folder to PATH" checkbox to ensure you can run "protractor", "grunt" into shell or batch command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will help I guess, Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem

1. In jenkins, just go to same directory where protractor and webdriver file is present after installing npm install -g protractor
2. like in build environment > cd go to same directory then
3. run commands with node appended to them such as

node webdriver-manager start
node protractor "path where config.js" is kept

This solution works for me!! Happy Automating

Answer (score 0):

This Issue occurs because if you have installed the NodeJS after starting the Jenkins server.

**The solution is simple:** 
Restart your Jenkins Server