# Protractor stopped working. Can you see why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

`Protractor` was running fine for me for weeks, testing for **Chrome** and **Firefox**. 
Then the **Chrome** tests started failing. 
Then `Protractor` wouldn't run at all. 
Then `Protractor` couldn't be found at all. 
Then I couldn't update or install it or anything else. 
I'm new at all this and I really have no idea what I'm doing.

A couple days ago, my manager had me `install Norton AV` on my computer. Could it be interfering somehow? If that's the case, what can I do??

Here's a sample error log from `NodeJS` when I tried to `install Protractor` again (running in Administrator Mode. I tried both in and out of Admin.):

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'protractor' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.4
3 info using node@v4.1.1
4 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
6 silly cache add args [ 'protractor', null ]
7 verbose cache add spec protractor
8 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
8 silly cache add   raw: 'protractor',
8 silly cache add   scope: null,
8 silly cache add   name: 'protractor',
8 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
8 silly cache add   spec: '*',
8 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
9 silly addNamed protractor@*
10 verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for protractor
11 silly addNameRange { name: 'protractor', range: '*', hasData: false }
12 silly mapToRegistry name protractor
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
16 verbose addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor not in flight; fetching
17 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
18 verbose request no auth needed
19 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:43:18 PM
20 verbose request id 76486ff9da2422de
21 verbose etag "D0VJJ2AW7ATP99LWOPYEA2JMU"
22 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
23 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
24 silly get cb [ 304,
24 silly get   { date: 'Fri, 16 Oct 2015 01:43:15 GMT',
24 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
24 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=60',
24 silly get     etag: '"D0VJJ2AW7ATP99LWOPYEA2JMU"',
24 silly get     age: '0',
24 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
24 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-iad2121-IAD',
24 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
24 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
24 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1444959795.437579,VS0,VE13',
24 silly get     vary: 'Accept' } ]
25 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor from cache
26 verbose get saving protractor to C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\protractor\.cache.json
27 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'protractor', range: '*', hasData: true }
28 silly addNameRange versions [ 'protractor',
28 silly addNameRange   [ '0.1.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.1.3',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.2.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.2.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.3.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.4.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.4.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.5.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.6.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.7.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.8.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.9.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.10.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.11.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.12.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.12.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.13.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.14.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.15.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.16.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.16.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.17.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.18.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.18.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.19.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.20.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.20.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.21.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.22.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.23.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.23.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.24.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.24.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '0.24.2',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc1',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc2',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc3',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc4',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc5',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc6',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.1.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.1.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.2.0-beta1',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.2.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.3.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.3.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.4.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.5.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.6.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.6.1',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.7.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '1.8.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '2.1.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '2.2.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '2.3.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '2.4.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '2.5.0',
28 silly addNameRange     '2.5.1' ] ]
29 silly addNamed protractor@2.5.1
30 verbose addNamed "2.5.1" is a plain semver version for protractor
31 silly cache afterAdd protractor@2.5.1
32 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\protractor\2.5.1\package\package.json not in flight; writing
33 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\protractor\2.5.1\package\package.json written
34 silly install resolved [ { name: 'protractor',
34 silly install resolved     description: 'Webdriver E2E test wrapper for Angular.',
34 silly install resolved     homepage: 'https://github.com/angular/protractor',
34 silly install resolved     keywords:
34 silly install resolved      [ 'angular',
34 silly install resolved        'test',
34 silly install resolved        'testing',
34 silly install resolved        'webdriver',
34 silly install resolved        'webdriverjs',
34 silly install resolved        'selenium' ],
34 silly install resolved     author: { name: 'Julie Ralph', email: 'ju.ralph@gmail.com' },
34 silly install resolved     dependencies:
34 silly install resolved      { request: '~2.57.0',
34 silly install resolved        'selenium-webdriver': '2.47.0',
34 silly install resolved        minijasminenode: '1.1.1',
34 silly install resolved        jasminewd: '1.1.0',
34 silly install resolved        jasminewd2: '0.0.6',
34 silly install resolved        jasmine: '2.3.2',
34 silly install resolved        saucelabs: '~1.0.1',
34 silly install resolved        glob: '~3.2',
34 silly install resolved        'adm-zip': '0.4.4',
34 silly install resolved        optimist: '~0.6.0',
34 silly install resolved        q: '1.0.0',
34 silly install resolved        lodash: '~2.4.1',
34 silly install resolved        'source-map-support': '~0.2.6',
34 silly install resolved        'html-entities': '~1.1.1',
34 silly install resolved        'accessibility-developer-tools': '~2.6.0' },
34 silly install resolved     devDependencies:
34 silly install resolved      { 'expect.js': '~0.2.0',
34 silly install resolved        chai: '~3.3.0',
34 silly install resolved        'chai-as-promised': '~5.1.0',
34 silly install resolved        jshint: '2.5.0',
34 silly install resolved        mocha: '2.3.3',
34 silly install resolved        cucumber: '~0.6.0',
34 silly install resolved        express: '~3.3.4',
34 silly install resolved        rimraf: '~2.2.6' },
34 silly install resolved     repository: { type: 'git', url: 'git://github.com/angular/protractor.git' },
34 silly install resolved     bin:
34 silly install resolved      { protractor: 'bin/protractor',
34 silly install resolved        'webdriver-manager': 'bin/webdriver-manager' },
34 silly install resolved     main: 'lib/protractor.js',
34 silly install resolved     scripts:
34 silly install resolved      { pretest: 'jshint lib spec scripts',
34 silly install resolved        test: 'node scripts/test.js',
34 silly install resolved        start: 'node testapp/scripts/web-server.js' },
34 silly install resolved     license: 'MIT',
34 silly install resolved     version: '2.5.1',
34 silly install resolved     gitHead: '645133d557f1059d9e885f2566fc4c29ce7c19cc',
34 silly install resolved     bugs: { url: 'https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues' },
34 silly install resolved     _id: 'protractor@2.5.1',
34 silly install resolved     _shasum: '03d6c93cd7c268f4250177d55a2fec8a198372cd',
34 silly install resolved     _from: 'protractor@*',
34 silly install resolved     _npmVersion: '2.11.3',
34 silly install resolved     _nodeVersion: '0.12.7',
34 silly install resolved     _npmUser: { name: 'angularcore', email: 'angular-core+npm@google.com' },
34 silly install resolved     dist:
34 silly install resolved      { shasum: '03d6c93cd7c268f4250177d55a2fec8a198372cd',
34 silly install resolved        tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/protractor/-/protractor-2.5.1.tgz' },
34 silly install resolved     maintainers: [ [Object], [Object] ],
34 silly install resolved     directories: {},
34 silly install resolved     _resolved: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor/-/protractor-2.5.1.tgz',
34 silly install resolved     readme: 'ERROR: No README data found!' } ]
35 info install protractor@2.5.1 into C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm
36 info installOne protractor@2.5.1
37 verbose installOne of protractor to C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm not in flight; installing
38 verbose lock using C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\protractor-1bab00a4fe7a23a0.lock for C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
39 silly install write writing protractor 2.5.1 to C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
40 verbose unbuild node_modules\protractor
41 silly gentlyRm C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor is being purged from base C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm
42 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
43 silly vacuum-fs purging C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
44 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\protractor-1bab00a4fe7a23a0.lock for C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
45 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe'
45 verbose stack     at Error (native)
46 verbose cwd C:\Users\travi\OneDrive\Documents\Protractor\sign in automation - take 1
47 error Windows_NT 10.0.10240
48 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "protractor"
49 error node v4.1.1
50 error npm  v2.14.4
51 error path C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe
52 error code EPERM
53 error errno -4048
54 error syscall unlink
55 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe'
55 error     at Error (native)
55 error  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe']
55 error   errno: -4048,
55 error   code: 'EPERM',
55 error   syscall: 'unlink',
55 error   path: 'C:\\Users\\travi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe' }
56 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
57 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
58 verbose unbuild node_modules\protractor
59 silly gentlyRm C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor is being purged from base C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm
60 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
61 silly vacuum-fs purging C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
62 error error rolling back Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe'
62 error error rolling back     at Error (native)
62 error error rolling back  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe']
62 error error rolling back   errno: -4048,
62 error error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
62 error error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
62 error error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\travi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe' }
```

#

**Update**:

I had tried `npm cache clean` several times, but then I `deleted the contents of %appdata%/npm-cache` Per Nocturno, now here is where I am:

```
C:\Users\travi>npm cache clean

C:\Users\travi>Protractor
'Protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\travi>npm install protractor

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\travi\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\travi\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not fi
nd WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid versio
n number. [C:\Users\travi\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-va
lidate\build\validation.vcxproj]
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\travi\node_mo
dules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\travi\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\travi\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

That error, EPERM seen on line 45, is an npm permission error. It can be fixed with `npm cache clean`, then you may or may not have to remove everything in the `%APPDATA%\npm-cache` directory.

Comment: I updated based on your suggestions. I have a new set of errors now.

Comment: See this question for that new problem - [Protractor is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931472/protractor-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progra).