# how to run autoIT through Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, selenium, jenkins, protractor, autoit

I am trying to run my protractor scripts through **Jenkins**, I have a script where `autoIT` need to execute, to upload a file.

When i run protractor command through "*Execute Windows batch command*" i get the following error:

```
" 'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file. "
```

I have set the **Jenkins** slave path. Could any one please help to solve this. 
When i run through **SSH command**, protractor was able to run but could not start execution of "`autoIT`".

Comment: It seems that the problem is in your batch command, not in autoit.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23931472/1879699

Comment: @guy can you suggest me something, what should i do to run my batch command?
so if i run through "Execute Windows batch command" will the autoIT works?

Comment: Add your command to the post. I'm not sure I will be able to help but I'm pretty sure someone will. AutoIt should work as it compiled with your script.